# Why is returning data from a .then() resulting in an object promise being passed back no matter what the input is?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I've been trying to get web javascript to fetch some dynamic data from a URL and store it in a variable.
However, for some reason anything that I return from the then() functions becomes an object promise, even if I wrote "return x;" where x is a string/array/etc..

Here's the code that I currently have.
The response from "api/fullGameData" is `{"fullGameData":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}`

```
let fullGameData = fetch("api/fullGameData")
.then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    }
)

fullGameData = fullGameData.then((json) => {
    let fullGameData = json.fullGameData;
    console.log("test= " + fullGameData);
    return fullGameData;
})

console.log("fullGameData= " + fullGameData);
```

I expected both of the console.logs in there to print the exact same thing, but no matter what I do the console says

```
fullGameData= [object Promise]
test= 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and I have no idea why. I've tried putting other console.logs in other places but it's always the same result, `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` if the console.log is in one of the .then() functions and `[object Promise]` otherwise. I really need to use the contents of the `fullGameData` variable elsewhere so I can't just do everything in the .then functions.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: tl;dr: You cannot.

Comment: You can use async await.

Comment: "*Why is returning data from a .then() resulting in an object promise*" - because calling `.then()` always returns a promise. It cannot return the result from the future, the handler has not yet been called, the best you can get is a promise for that eventual result.

Comment: "*I really need to use the contents of the `fullGameData` variable elsewhere so I can't just do everything in the .then functions.*" - yes you can. Please show us that code "elsewhere" if you need help with how to access the data.

Comment: @Bergi What I have right now to come after is this, it uses Phaser, tileset is statically preloaded
`let map = this.add.tilemap({data: mapData, tileWidth: 188, tileHeight: 176});`
`let tiles = map.addTilesetImage('tileset');`
`let mainLayer = map.createLayer(0,'tiles');`
I'm pretty sure there's going to be more lines of code after this once I figure this part out and see that they work, but I don't know what exactly will come next yet. 
I suppose I could cram everything inside the .then(), but then it'd be an indentation nightmare and just a lot more unreadable so I want to avoid it.

Comment: There should be only one level of indentation, no more. It's either in a function that you can just call from the `.then()` callback, or it's in the `.then()` callback itself. Either way, it's impossible to put this code in the top level of a script, since it cannot be executed immediately but needs to wait for the game data to load - but it's not desirable to declare these variables (`map`, `tiles`, `mainlayer`) in the global scope anyway.

Comment: I tried the function thing, but then the `this.add.tilemap` broke, presumably because of `this`. I tried async await next and it seems to work now, though. Boy, I really need to get used to promises this is confusing ;)

Comment: What is `this`? Is that code already part of a class method or something?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I'm writing the code inside a framework and I just know that I should use `this`, I don't know what's going on under the hood. You can look it up if you're interested ig, it's phaser.io :)

Comment: Doesn't matter what framework this is, just what the surrounding lexical structure is. A class method? A function declaration? An arrow function? Top level of the module?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's a class method, but honestly I have no idea. :| 
Would you like to look at the entire script?